# How to use variables in re.findall?

Tags: python, list, python-re

I'm extremely new to Python, so I'm sorry if my question is rather stupid.
I have a bunch of long strings in one list and shortened parts of it in another list

Like:

Long string is D:\\Python\\Songs\\testsong.mp3 and short string is \\testsong.mp3

And I want to get a list containing 'Songs' (basically the name of the folder containing the mp3) but I have multiple folders and multiple songs so I'm trying to use re.findall but it only accepts defined patterns and my patterns change due to different songs names.

Comment: look for `glob`. Iterate over the given directory and then match the files inside if they meet a certain condition (i.e. `mp3` in the extension) append the dir name to a list!

Comment: Or you could do the same using `os.walk()`

Comment: How do I do that? Could you help me with a sample?

Comment: Added an answer below. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

```
from pathlib import Path

directories = [
    "D:/Python/Songs/testsong.mp3",
    "C:/users/xyz/desktop/anothersong.mp3"
]

song_folder_names = set(Path(directory).parts[-2] for directory in directories)
print(song_folder_names)
```

Output:

```
{'desktop', 'Songs'}
>>>
```

Notice, that the order of the folder names is not preserved - because I'm using a `set`.

Comment: @StevenWilliam Glad it's working! Let me know if you have any questions.